# Flash Error 2012 Can't instantiate Shared Object class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have no idea why i am getting this error can somebody please tell me.. what causes this error and how to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're using `new SharedObject()`, but Shared Objects are a bit different from normal. Instead of trying to create a new instance yourself, you should be using `SharedObject.getLocal` like this:

```
private var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("application-name");
```

But obviously change "application-name" to be something specific to your project.

There is a more detailed example in the documentation here: [Shared Object Examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: Also note that an exception will occur if the user has disabled the SharedObject in the Flash Player settings panel. The call to SharedObject.getLocal() should be wrapped in a try/catch block because of this.